# CNN: how to improve prediction speed?

Tags: performance, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

I use a CNN (Keras/Theano) to recognize given numbers in a sudoku puzzle. Because I display the solution in an "augmented reality" way, I am looking for minimizing the speed for the image processing task and for number recognition task, so that the display keeps smooth. Currently, I get a rate of 7 frame per second (you can have a look here : [Augmented Reality Sudoku solver : OpenCV, Keras](https://youtu.be/QR66rMS_ZfA) )

A big part of the processing time is spent in the prediction task : the prediction is made for every small non empty square (square with a number in it). On average, one prediction takes 3.6 ms, an puzzle has about 25 non empty squares, so about 90 ms per image just for the recognition of the given numbers.

The CNN model I use for the prediction task is almost exactly the one proposed by F.Chollet in the [Keras MNIST example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) :

```
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28 # Image size of the small square
num_classes = 9  # We want to recognize the numbers from 1 to 9
input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The accuracy I get with this model is very good, so good that I wonder if I can get the same accuracy with a "smaller" model. I imagine that smaller model would also mean faster (I only focus on prediction speed improvement, training speed doesn't matter).

Do you think my assumption ("smaller implies faster") is correct and is it worth to try to make a smaller model ? Between the convolutionnal part and the dense part, which one(s) I should try to make smaller ?

Any other suggestion on how to improve the prediction speed ?

Thank you

EDIT:

My CPU is an old i5 4210U, no nvidia GPU.

Prediction code:

```
def predict(img): # img: 28x28 binary image

   img = img.astype('float32')
   img /= 255.
   result=model.predict(np.array([[img]]))
   result=result[0]        
   idx=np.argsort(result)
   best=idx[-1]+1
   return best,result[best-1]
```

Comment: There is no code of your prediction-task. And are you even telling us if you use CPU/GPU (latency!)? In general, yes, smaller will be faster, but that's very broad and to be taken with a grain of salt as parallelization could also be hurt. Make sure, you are using batch-prediction if you are able to call for multiple-predictions at once!

Comment: sascha, I edited my question to add the prediction code. I wasn't aware of the importance of batch_size in predict function. Actually, it is not clear for me how to use it in the prediction task. Because I don't specify it, the default batch_size is 32, I think. Until now, I predict image (small square with a number in it) per image. I will follow your suggestion to make multiple-predictions at once and let you know. Thanks

Comment: It is really worth to use multiples-predictions. For a 27 numbers sudoku, doing 1 multi-prediction (instead of 27 single number prediction) needs 67 ms (instead of 97 ms), so a gain of 30 ms. Now I get a global rate of 9 frame per second, instead of 7 fps, 30% better ! I kept the default value of batch_size (32).

Comment: @sascha Big speed improvement by simplifying my CNN ! I have just removed the second convolutional layer, the validation accuracy stays very good (about 99.8%) but  now the prediction task for the whole numbers needs only 12ms (to compare with 67ms before). Now it is even fast enough to transparently deal with full rotation of the sudoku puzzle ([link]https://youtu.be/Ob3MW_DKkNA)